# An integral-formula multivariate Talyor's theorem for twice differentiable function

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

In [1], I encounter the following statement:

For $ f: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ that is twice differentiable,

$ \nabla f (x + p) - \nabla f (x) = \int_{0}^{1} \nabla^{2} f (x + t p) ~ p ~ dt $,

which is named as "Taylor's theorem".

Can someone help me prove the statement?

In particular, does this statement hold even if the function $f$ is more than twice differentiable? I am confused because there could be a nonzero residual term if the function $f$ is more than twice differentiable.

Thanks a lot.

[1] J. Nocedal, S. J. Wright, Numerical Optimization, 2nd Edition,
Springer Series in Operations Research and Financial Engineering,
Springer, New York, NY, 2006, ISBN-10: 0387303030

Comment: The statement appears as Theorem 2.1 (Taylor's Theorem), equation (2.5) on page 14.

Comment: You can go to any order Taylor provided $f$ is at least $p$ times differentiable with continuity: basically do
$$
f(x+h) = T_{p-1}f(x) \cdot h + \int_0^1 \frac{(1-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} D^pf(x+th) \cdot h^{(p)} dt.
$$
The authors are using this formula for $p = 1$ and the function is $\nabla f.$

Comment: @WilliamM. Could you tell me what you mean by $T_{p-1}$?

Comment: @WilliamM. So the notation $h^{(p)}$ means $h$ raised to the power of $p$, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Taylor of $f$ at $x$ of degree $p-1$, this is a polynomial evaluated at $h.$ The polynomial is defined as $f(x) + Df(x) \cdot h + \ldots + \frac{1}{(p-1)!}D^{p-1}f(x) \cdot h^{(p-1)},$ where $h^{(k)} = (h,\ldots,h)$ ($k$ times). The proof of these results can be found in Cartan's differential calculus.

Comment: @WilliamM. Thanks. I am trying to get Differential Calculus written by Henry Cartan, now.

Comment: @WilliamM. It feels awkward that the statement holds for $f$ that is more than twice differentiable...

Comment: It holds in $\mathbf{R}$, so why not in a general normed space? https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/361F15/Notes/Taylor-integral.pdf

Comment: Okay. I see your argument in the book written by Cartan, but for nonzero $h$ and a function $f$ having higher differentiability, e.g., infinitely many times differentiable $f$, the statement from the book written by Nocedal and Write does not hold due to the nonzero terms beyond the Hessian.

Answer (score 0):

On page 70 in [2], we have Theorem 5.6.1 (Taylor's formula with integral remainder). However, this equation is for $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Thus, let us use the extension in higher dimensions [3] from Wikipedia.

**Taylor's Theorem for Multivariate Functions**

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $k+1$-times continuously differentiable function in a closed ball $\mathcal{B} = \{\ \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}: \|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y} \| \leq h \}$ for some $h > 0$. Then, for any $\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h} \in \mathcal{B}$ we have

$ f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h}) = 
\sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} \frac{D^{\alpha} f(\mathbf{x})}{\alpha!} \mathbf{h}^{\alpha} + \sum_{|\beta| = k + 1} \int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{(1 - t)^{|\beta| - 1}}{(\beta - 1)!}
 D^{\beta} f (\mathbf{x} + t \mathbf{h}) \mathbf{h}^{\beta}~dt.
$

For the statement

$
\nabla f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h}) - \nabla f (\mathbf{x}) = \int_{0}^{1} \nabla^{2} f (\mathbf{x} + t \mathbf{h}) \mathbf{h}~dt
$

in Theorem 2.1 (Taylor's Theorem) of [1], equation (2.5), to hold for any ${f \in \mathcal{C}^{k + 1}}$ with ${\forall k \geq 1}$,

we only need to ensure the notation

$\nabla^{k} f = D^{k} f \in \mathbb{R}^{d_{1} \times ... \times d_{k}}$ hold with ${d_{i} = d}$ for ${i = \{1, ..., k\}}$.

[1] J. Nocedal, S. J. Wright, Numerical Optimization, 2nd Edition, Springer Series in Operations Research and Financial Engineering, Springer, New York, NY, 2006, ISBN-10: 0387303030

[2] Cartan, H. Differential Calculus, Hermann, Paris, 1971.

[3] Königsberger Analysis 2, p. 64 ff.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#cite_ref-14

Comment: Let me know if there is an alternative opinion.

Comment: this equation is simply an application of the fundamental theorem of calculus. It doesn’t need the full strength of Taylor’s theorem.

Comment: Theorem (5.6.1) and its eq. (5.6.2) are for functions $f:U \to F$ where $U$ is an open set of a normed space and $F$ is another normed space. And yes, @peek-a-boo, Taylor's theorem with integral follows immediately from the FTC and this is how Cartan proves Taylor's theorem on Corollary (5.5.2).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments both of you as I learned something from the comments. However, what I speculated was whether the same behavior $\nabla f(x + p) - \nabla f(x) = \int_{0}^{1} \nabla^{2} f (x + tp) ~ p ~ dt$ holds, which turns out that is not true if the function $f$ has a higher differentiability than $C^{2}$.

Comment: No, the statement of the theorem in your book holds for any function at least twice differentiable with continuity (so, many more than only those which are __exactly__ twice differentiable).

Comment: @WilliamM. I have updated my self-answer, adding theorem 5.6.1 from the book written by Cartan, and then I deduce the statement in the book written by Nocedal and Wright for exactly twice differentiable functions. Could you help me see the statement from Nocedal and Wright also for functions that have higher differentiability beyond $C^{2}$? **How do the higher-order terms vanish in the Taylor series form?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: A function of class $C^{p+k}$ is also of class $C^p.$ If $f$ is of class $C^3$ then $f(x+h)-f(x) =\int_0^1 dt Df(x+th) \cdot h = f'(x) \cdot h + \int_0^1 dt (1-t) D^2f(x+th) \cdot (h,h) = f'(x) \cdot h + \frac{1}{2} f''(x) \cdot (h,h) + \int_0^1 dt \frac{1}{2}(1-t)^2 D^3f(x+th) \cdot (h,h,h)...$ all of these follow from Theorem 5.6.1 of Cartan's book.

Comment: @WilliamM. Thanks a lot! From your comment, I improved my understanding of Theorem 5.6.1 in Cartan's book. Now, I am trying to understand how this transfers to higher dimensions.

Comment: @WilliamM. I brought the multivariate version of Taylor's theorem from Wikipedia to modify my self-answer. Is the answer reasonable? Could you add or modify this answer to complete this post? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @WilliamM. The thing is, I barely have experience with the differential operator, but mostly I am familiar with the nabla and Hessian. So, I can not immediately take my self-answer as the accepted answer. I hoped you could confirm if there is no issue or give an edit to the answer. :-)